# open small window on click - like google menu (html/MVC 4)

Tags: html, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am trying to create a google like menu. Specificly I want the behavior of the app button in google's menu - on click a small windo is opened under the button/image, with a small arrow.
I have not been able to find a example like that. What i found mostly was links that open a new window (with full menu bar on top).
I am using HTML/MVC 4, an if necessary kendo and jquery.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://kendo-labs.github.io/kendo-plugins/#/ContextMenu at Kendo Labs at https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-plugins.

Attach the context menu to the arrow icon in your main menu.

Comment: Turns out kendo is not working out for me, is there another way?